# Is there a LESS CSS based version / project of the ZURB Foundation 4 Framework?

Tags: sass, less, zurb-foundation

I'm currently working on new projects and I'll be using the Foundation 4 Framework (foundation.zurb.com). I checked the web up and down but couldn't find a project (GitHub or otherwise) that ported the SASS logic of Foundation 4 to LESS.

I really like Foundation 4 and I would love to work with SASS but as reality forces me to not use ruby for development, I'm down to using the pure CSS version of Foundation 4. I would prefer to use it with less, which I can easily include in my PHP workflow and porting all the SASS goodness to LESS is quite a bit of work. I am fully aware that some parts of the Foundation SASS logic won't work with LESS, but that is a price I'm willing to pay.

I found a grunt project (github.com/jonschlinkert/grunt-refactor) that offers/promises some degree of porting logic but as I never worked with grunt/node.js before, I couldn't get that working until now.

Do you know of a Foundation 4 LESS port?

Comment: You don't have to be using Ruby for web development to use Sass (I'm using Haskell).

Comment: Most of my clients and partners are not willing to switch to anything new. Therefor a LESS port would be great.

Comment: One Team im currently working in has a PHP setup with LESSphp and mixing LESS and SASS would be to much overhead/learning curve for them.

Answer (score 0):

Someone tried to create a fork in Foundation3 that was done in LESS but they eventually dropped it. You can find full discussion about this here: https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/370. I don't know about any other porting to LESS attemps.

Comment: After reading that issue and other related issues, there seem to be quite a few attempts but none that is still alive.